# ConfigObj way to get list of sections that contain subsections

Tags: python, parsing

I use ConfigObj to parse config file in format:

```
[APACHE]
init_script=
...
[TOMCAT]
    [[TOMCAT1]]
    init_script =
    [[TOMCAT2]]
    init_script =
```

In some condition [TOMCAT] section may have nested subsection,sometime not - only single root instance [TOMCAT] .

I'm fresh in python so interesting, is there a convenient way to walk through config file and get only elements that contain nested subsection elements.

Currently I use such approach:

```
def is_section(config_section):
    """
       Check that config elemet is a section
    """
    try:
     config_section.keys()
    except AttributeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
onfig = ConfigObj(config_file,list_values=True,interpolation=True)

sections = config.keys()

for section in sections:
     if is_section(config[section]):
        for subsection in config[section]:
            if is_section(config[section][subsection]):
                print  "Subsection ", subsection
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `walk` and print section that have a `depth` greater than one.

```
def gather_subsection(section, key):
    if section.depth > 1:
        print "Subsection " + section.name

config.walk(gather_subsection)
```

[Documentation for depth](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#id62)

> **depth**
>
> The nesting level of the current
>   section.
>
> If you create a new ConfigObj and add
>   sections, 1 will be added to the depth
>   level between sections.

[Documentation for walk](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#id64)